Euclidean distance from arbitrary number of columns
I'm trying to compute euclidean distance based on an arbitrary list of columns. I made an attempt to do this to compute the distance between observations in dt and the single observation in x. This seems to compute as expected but I get a warning on line 4 because I'm not assigning by reference.
dt <- data.table(a=1:10, b=11:20, c=21:30)
x <- data.table(a=5, b=6, c=7)
for(i in names(dt)){
  dt[[i]] <- (dt[[i]] - x[1][[i]])^2
}
dt[, euclid := rowSums(.SD), .SDcols=names(dt)]
dt[, euclid := sqrt(euclid)]

So then I replaced line 4 with setattr(dt, i, (dt[[i]] - x[1][[i]])^2) but then it doesn't actually update the columns.
I may be misunderstanding how setattr() works. I thought the following two lines would be equivalent but apparently not.
dt[, foo := 2]
setattr(dt, "foo", 2)

I would welcome any thoughts as well as advice on doing this in a better way.
I have data.table v1.15.4

setattr sets attributes of the object, it doesn't update values, are you thinking of data.table::set for that? (Not that I think that's the right way to go, tbh)

Something like this?
cols <- c("a", "b", "c")
dt[, euclid := sqrt(rowSums(mapply(function(a, b) (a-b)^2,
                                   .SD, x[, .SD, .SDcols = cols]))),
    .SDcols = cols]
#         a     b     c   euclid
#     <int> <int> <int>    <num>
#  1:     1    11    21 15.39480
#  2:     2    12    22 16.43168
#  3:     3    13    23 17.57840
#  4:     4    14    24 18.81489
#  5:     5    15    25 20.12461
#  6:     6    16    26 21.49419
#  7:     7    17    27 22.91288
#  8:     8    18    28 24.37212
#  9:     9    19    29 25.86503
# 10:    10    20    30 27.38613

It seems a little Inception to be using x[, .SD] inside of dt[, ...] ...

Thank you. Definitely my first time seeing an x[, .SD] inside of a dt[,..] :-)

Here is one approach while not changing the original column values
cbind(dt, 
  dt[, lapply(names(.SD), \(i) (.SD[,get(i)] - x[,get(i)])^2)][
    , .(euclid = sqrt(rowSums(.SD)))])
        a     b     c   euclid
    <int> <int> <int>    <num>
 1:     1    11    21 15.39480
 2:     2    12    22 16.43168
 3:     3    13    23 17.57840
 4:     4    14    24 18.81489
 5:     5    15    25 20.12461
 6:     6    16    26 21.49419
 7:     7    17    27 22.91288
 8:     8    18    28 24.37212
 9:     9    19    29 25.86503
10:    10    20    30 27.38613


Probably you can try this
> dt[, euclid := sqrt(rowSums((.SD - unlist(x)[col(.SD)])^2))][]
        a     b     c   euclid
    <int> <int> <int>    <num>
 1:     1    11    21 15.39480
 2:     2    12    22 16.43168
 3:     3    13    23 17.57840
 4:     4    14    24 18.81489
 5:     5    15    25 20.12461
 6:     6    16    26 21.49419
 7:     7    17    27 22.91288
 8:     8    18    28 24.37212
 9:     9    19    29 25.86503
10:    10    20    30 27.38613


dt[, euclid := sqrt(colSums((t(.SD) - unlist(x))**2))][]

        a     b     c   euclid
    <int> <int> <int>    <num>
 1:     1    11    21 15.39480
 2:     2    12    22 16.43168
 3:     3    13    23 17.57840
 4:     4    14    24 18.81489
 5:     5    15    25 20.12461
 6:     6    16    26 21.49419
 7:     7    17    27 22.91288
 8:     8    18    28 24.37212
 9:     9    19    29 25.86503
10:    10    20    30 27.38613

